# removeAll() thymeleaf. Вложенные циклы

Tags: java, циклы, thymeleaf

Есть 2 листа:

Лист всех позиций `(th:each="allPosition:${positionList}")`

И лист позиций у воркера `(th:each="workerPosition : ${worker.allPosition}")`

Как используя **removeAll** удалить из листа всех позиций, все позиции воркера и вывести полученный лист.

Например:
Есть 1 лист содержит 1,2,3,4

2 лист содержит 1,2

Результат должен быть такой: 3,4

```
<h3 style="color: black" align="center">Все Должности</h3>
  <div  th:each="allPosition:${positionList}">
      <input id="pos3" type="checkbox" th:value="${allPosition.id}"
             name="allPosition" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
      <label for="pos3"><h3 style="color: black;font-size: 30px"
                           th:text="${allPosition.jobName}"></h3></label>


      <h3 style="color: black;" align="center">Активные Должности</h3>
      <div th:each="position : ${worker.allPosition}">
          <div>
              <input id="pos4" type="checkbox" th:value="${position.id}"  th:checked="checked" name="allPosition" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
              <label for="pos4"><h3 style="color: black;font-size: 30px" 
                                th:text="${position.jobName}"></h3></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: логикак во view - это плохая практика